# Should I remove system hdd with windows 7 TrueCrypt encrypton before making it dual boot with Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, compatibility

The system hdd is just one partition, windows 7 installed and the whole partition encrypted by TrueCrypt.
Should I remove that before making new partition and installing Ubuntu on it (dual boot)
infact will i even be able to make new partition?

Comment: I would recommend you do so, so you have no problems at all during the installation.

tell me what happends :)

Answer (score 0):

The *TrueCrypt documentation* mentions that you can decrypt ***system partitions and system drives*** and to do this select *System > Permanently Decrypt System Partition/Drive*. After having the partition *decrypted*, *resize* the HDD manually (with partition manager of your choice) or just allow Ubuntu installation to handle it (install alongside Ubuntu). You may then *re-encrypt* the windows partition.

These links should help:

- [Encrypting a Linux/Windows dual-boot system](https://www.ices.utexas.edu/sysdocs/encryption/winlinux.html)
- [Boot Linux using Windows 7 boot loader](http://blog.famzah.net/2011/11/12/boot-linux-using-windows-7-boot-loader/)

Comment: When i re-encrypt the windows partition, will it ask for the pre-boot password only when windows is selected to be booted or even before the boot loader?